# Quotient by annihilator of an element is an injective module

Tags: modules, injective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $M$ be an $R$ module and $m\in M$.

I am trying to prove or disprove that $M/ann(m)$ is an injective $R$ module. Any suggestions are welcome.

I am expecting the answer to be yes. I was trying to prove that given any $R$ module $M$ there exists an $R$ module $I$ with an injective morphism $M\rightarrow I$ i.e., to prove that there are enough injectives in the category of $R$ modules. Idea is to prove that the above quotient is an injective module and so is the product of quotients over all elements of $M$ with natrural (which I expect to be injective)map $M\rightarrow \prod_{m\in M} M/ann(m)$.

Comment: To be clear, by $M/ann(m)$ you mean $M/IM$ where $I\subseteq R$ is the ideal of all $r\in R$ such that $rm=0$?  In any case, I would suggest considering some simple examples to see whether this seems to be true...

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, that is what I mean and I think it is usual notation. I am using tab where I can not type so much latex. I have not checked any examples yet. I will check.

Comment: Why are you expecting this to be true?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it is just plain intuition. I can not express as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually not true (indeed, it's harder to come up with a nontrivial example where it is true than one where it isn't true).  For instance, take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $m=1$.  Then $ann(m)=0$, so $M/ann(m)=\mathbb{Z}$ which is not an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

For an example where $ann(m)M$ is nonzero, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, and $m=(1,0)$.  Then $ann(m)=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $M/ann(m)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not injective.

Really, I cannot see any reason why you would expect something like this to be true.  If you do not have any motivating examples or any inkling of how to prove a similar statement, there is no reason at all to imagine you are on the right track.

Comment: +1 but, Can you think of some example where annihilator ideal is not the whole ring? I should have written that in the question it self. If I am allowing elements where annihilator is zero, the map M \rightarrow \prod M/ann(m)$ is injective obviously. I am thinking even if I ignore the elements where annihilator is zero, the map is injective

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will keep your advice when I guess something next time.